# Type checking class static variables in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, static-variables, typechecking, python-typing

I have the following Python code in a PyCharm project:

```py
class Category:
    text: str

a = Category()
a.text = 1.5454654  # where is the warning?
```

The editor is supposed to show a warning as I'm trying to set an attribute with a wrong type. Have a look below at the settings below:

[image: screenshot of PyCharm settings configuration]

Comment: What python version are you using?  And how is your Pycharm configured relating to that? Enabling `TypeChecker` will only work if the `TypeChecker` used can detect the type error/warning, and it's not clear in your question here what is _actually_ used to check the type...

Comment: @Jean-BenoitHarvey - the version is 2020.3, the problem is that if text property is `str`, I why don't I see a warning when setting text = number? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug, [PyCharm implements its own static type checker](https://github.com/python/mypy#ide-linter-integrations-and-pre-commit), if you try [the same code using MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=2b31252308dffd3d6de511ad8126d6b5) the static type checker will emit the warnings. Changing IDE configurations does not change this, the only way is using a different Linter.

I slightly altered the code to make sure a docstring wouldn't make a difference.

```py
class Category:
    """Your docstring.

    Attributes:
        text(str): a description.
    """

    text: str


a = Category()

Category.text = 11  # where is the warning?
a.text = 1.5454654  # where is the warning?
```

MyPy does give the following warnings:

> ```
> main.py:13: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "str")
> main.py:14: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "float", variable has type "str")
> Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
> ```

*EDIT:* In the comments it was pointed out there's a bug report [PY-36889 on JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36889).

It's also worth mentioning, by the way, that the example in the question sets a static class variable but also rebinds it by setting the value on an instance. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69067) gives a lengthy explanation.

```py
>>> Category.text = 11
>>> a.text = 1.5454654  
>>> a.text
1.5454654
>>> Category.text
11
```

Comment: There is in fact a bug filed for this: [PY-36889](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36889). Hasn't been fixed after a year, though.