# PyCharm gives me a type warning about my metaclass; mypy disagrees

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, mypy, metaclass

I was trying to write a metaclass named `Singleton`, that, of course, implement the singleton design pattern:

```py
class Singleton(type):
    
  def __new__(cls, name, bases = None, attrs = None):
    if bases is None:
      bases = ()
        
    if attrs is None:
      attrs = {}
        
    new_class = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    new_class._instance = None
    return new_class
    
  def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if cls._instance is None:
      cls._instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
      cls.__init__(cls._instance, *args, **kwargs)
        
    return cls._instance
```

This seems to work correctly:

```py
class Foo(metaclass = Singleton):
  pass

foo1 = Foo()
foo2 = Foo()

print(foo1 is foo2)  # True
```

However, PyCharm gave me this warning for `cls._instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`:

```
Expected type 'Type[Singleton]', got 'Singleton' instead
```

...and this for `cls.__init__(cls._instance, *args, **kwargs)`:

```
Expected type 'str', got 'Singleton' instead
```

I ran mypy on the same file, and here's what it said:

```
# mypy test.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

I'm using Python 3.11, PyCharm 2023.1.1 and mypy 1.3.0 if that makes a difference.

So what exactly is the problem here? Am I doing this correctly? Is this a bug with PyCharm, with mypy or something else? If the error is on me, how can I fix it?

Comment: IIRC Pycharm lets you configure what typechecker to use.  What typechecker is it using?

Comment: @Samwise It does? I don't recall touching such a config. How do I find it? `Ctrl-Shift-A` + `type checker`  returns nothing.

Comment: ah, apparently Pycharm is one of the IDEs that *doesn't* let you configure a typechecker (I used Pycharm at one point but switched to vscode a while back and must have assumed pycharm works the same way).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65508011/type-checking-class-static-variables-in-pycharm

Comment: When I run `mypy --strict` over that Singleton definition, I get all sorts of errors, even discounting the ones about missing annotations.

Comment: Regardless of the question: I would not advise having a metaclass just to create singletons (I am not sure who started this trend, but it is just overkill). And: you don't need the `__new__`  method on your metaclass at all - just use `getattr` with None as a sentinel valule in your `__call__`.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/singleton_is_a_bad_idea.html before putting too much effort into "fixing" this metaclass.

Comment: @chepner It's for practicing, so whether the design pattern is bad or not is actually irrelevant. I do know that I shouldn't use it, and I won't, in production code, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), I'll start with the solution to *X*. The answers for *Y* are further down.

---

### Solution

There is no need for manually calling `cls.__new__` and then `cls.__init__` in `Singleton.__call__`. You can just call `super().__call__` instead, just like @Grismar did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76225286).

There is also no need for a custom `Singleton.__new__` method at all, if all you want to do is set up the singleton pattern in a type safe manner.

And to have a `_instance = None` fallback in your classes, you can just define and assign that attribute on the meta class.

Here is the minimal setup required:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any


class Singleton(type):
    _instance: Singleton | None = None

    def __call__(cls, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Singleton:
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


class Foo(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
```

This passes `mypy --strict` and causes no PyCharm warnings. You said you wanted `_instance` to be saved in each *class* not in the *meta class*. This is the case here. Try the following:

```py
foo1 = Foo()
foo2 = Foo()

print(foo1 is foo2)           # True
print(foo1 is Foo._instance)  # True
print(Singleton._instance)    # None
```

If you *do* want a custom meta class `__new__` method, it requires a lot more boilerplate to set up in a type safe manner, due to the overloaded `type` constructor. But here is a template that should work in all situations:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T", bound=type)


class Singleton(type):
    _instance: Singleton | None = None

    @overload
    def __new__(mcs, o: object, /) -> type: ...

    @overload
    def __new__(
        mcs: type[T],
        name: str,
        bases: tuple[type, ...],
        namespace: dict[str, Any],
        /,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> T: ...

    def __new__(
        mcs,
        name: Any,
        bases: Any = (),
        namespace: Any = None,
        /,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> type:
        if namespace is None:
            namespace = {}
        # do other things here...
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

    def __call__(cls, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Singleton:
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

The `__new__` overloads closely resemble those in the [typeshed stubs](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/builtins.pyi).

But again, that is not necessary for the *singleton-via-metaclass* pattern.

Digging deeper into your type inference questions sent me down a rabbit hole, so the explanations got a little longer. But I thought it more useful to present the solution to your *actual* problem up front (because it circumvents the errors). So if you are interested in the explanations, keep reading.

---

### Why does `cls.__new__` expect `type[Singleton]`?

I get the same error from Mypy for your code:

```
Argument 1 to "__new__" of "Singleton" has incompatible type "Singleton"; expected "Type[Singleton]"
```

Recall that the [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method is an **instance** method. In the context of `Singleton.__call__`, the type of the first argument (in this case named `cls`) is inferred as `Singleton`.

Since you defined your own `Singleton.__new__` method, its (implicit) signature will be reflected in `cls.__new__`. You did not annotate `Singleton.__new__`, but type checkers typically fall back to "standard" inferences for special cases like the first parameter of a method.

[`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is a **static** method that takes a class as the first argument and returns an instance of it. The first argument to `Singleton.__new__` is therefore expected to be *the type* `type[Singleton]`, not *an instance* of `Singleton`.

So from the point of view of the type checker, by calling `cls.__new__(cls, ...)` you are passing an *instance* of `Singleton` as an argument, where a the type `Singleton` itself (or a subtype) is expected.

---

**Side note**:

This distinction can be quite confusing, which is one of the reasons why it is best practice to name the first parameter to `__new__` *differently* than the first parameter to a "normal" method.

In regular classes (not inheriting from `type`) the first parameter to normal methods should be called `self`, while the first parameter to `__new__` should be called `cls`.

In *meta* classes however, the conventions are not as ubiquitous, but common sense suggests that the normal methods' first parameter should be called `cls`, while the first parameter to `__new__` should be called `mcs` (or `mcls` or something like that). It is just very useful to highlight the distinction in the nature of that first argument. But these are all conventions of course and the interpreter doesn't care either way.

---

Whether or not this inference of `cls.__new__` as `Singleton.__new__` is justified or sensible is debatable.

Since `cls` in that context will always be an *instance* of the surrounding (meta) class, I would argue that it does not make sense to expect `cls.__new__` to ever resolve to the `__new__` method of said (meta) class.

In fact, unless the class `cls` itself defines a custom `__new__` method, it will fall back to `object.__new__`, not to `Singleton.__new__`:

```py
class Singleton(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(cls.__new__)
        print(cls.__new__ is object.__new__)
        print(cls.__new__ is Singleton.__new__)

class Foo(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass

foo1 = Foo()
```

Output:

```
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x...>
True
False
```

`object.__new__` indeed *does* accept `Singleton` as its first argument because it is a class and the return type would be an instance of it. So there is nothing wrong or unsafe about the way you called `cls.__new__` as far as I can tell.

We can see the wrong type inference by the type checker even more clearly, if we add a custom `__new__` to `Singleton` and run it through the type checker:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any


class Singleton(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name: str, bases: Any = None, attrs: Any = None) -> Singleton:
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)

    def __call__(cls, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        reveal_type(cls.__new__)
        ...
```

Mypy wrongly infers the type as follows:

```
Revealed type is "def (mcs: Type[Singleton], name: builtins.str, bases: Any =, attrs: Any =) -> Singleton"
```

So it clearly expects `cls.__new__` to be `Singleton.__new__`, even though it is actually `object.__new__`.

As far as I understand it, the discrepancy between the actual method resolution and the one inferred by the type checker is due to the special-cased behavior for the [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method. It may also just have to do with meta classes being poorly supported by type checkers. But maybe someone more knowledgeable can clear this up. (Or I'll consult the issue tracker.)

---

### That pesky `__init__` call

The PyCharm message is nonsense of course. The problem seems to come down to the same faulty inference of `cls.__init__` as `type.__init__`, as opposed to `object.__init__`.

Mypy has an entirely different problem, complaining about the explicit usage of `__init__` on an instance with the following error:

```
Accessing "__init__" on an instance is unsound, since instance.__init__ could be from an incompatible subclass
```

The `__init__` method is intentionally excluded from [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) conformity requirements by mypy, which means that explicitly calling it is *technically* unsafe.

Not much else to say. Avoid that call, unless you are sure the overrides all the way up the [MRO](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order) chain for `__init__` are type safe; then use `# type: ignore[misc]`.

---

So to summarize, I believe these two warnings/errors are both false positives.

Comment: That is one well-researched answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're also asking "am I doing this correctly?", why don't you use a simpler solution like this:

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class Foo(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    ...


foo1 = Foo()
foo2 = Foo()

print(foo1 is foo2)  # still True
```

This avoids the construction causing the confusion and warning. I appreciate that I'm not answering the question why PyCharm is detecting type conflicts that you feel are incorrect - they may be, I didn't dig down deep enough to figure out why PyCharm might think this.

If you just want to get rid of the warning, after you've ascertained the problem is not correctly identified:

```
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    cls._instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

And if you find out what exactly is wrong, you should submit a bug report with JetBrains (and add a #todo to your #noinspection to remind yourself to remove it once it's fixed).

Comment: "*[...] why don't you use a simpler solution [..]*": Surely I can (I read all of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6760685) already), but I prefer to keep each `._instance` a part of its corresponding class rather than the metaclass. Also, there would be no point in writing it since this is for practicing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There's no arguing preferences of course - my reasoning went in the opposite direction: since the Singleton classes depend on the metaclass for being singleton, keeping track of information that only pertains to that aspect on the metaclass makes sense, and the fact that the solution is a lot simpler is a bonus. But @daniilfajnberg's answer makes a more important point: if you need the `__new__` for some more specific reason, you'll run into these issues, and then they are worth solving - his answer goes a long way to explain it.