# mypy & typing singleton / factory classes

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I often use the following construct to generate singletons in my code:

```
class Thing:
    pass


class ThingSingletonFactory:
    _thing = None

    def __new__(cls) -> Thing:
        if cls._thing is None:
            cls._thing = Thing()
        return cls._thing


def get_thing() -> Thing:
    return ThingSingletonFactory()


thing = get_thing()
same_thing = get_thing()

assert thing is same_thing
```

`class ThingSingletonFactory` stores the only instance of `Thing`, and returns it anytime a new `ThingSingletonFactory()` is requested. Works great for API clients, logging.Logger, etc.

I'm adding mypy type checking to an existing project that uses this, and mypy does not like it, at all.

```
line 8:  error: Incompatible return type for "__new__" (returns "Thing", but must return a subtype of "ThingSingletonFactory")  [misc]
line 15: error: Incompatible return value type (got "ThingSingletonFactory", expected "Thing")  [return-value]
```

I feel the type hints in the code are correct: `__new__()` does return the type Thing, as does the func `get_thing()`.

How can I provide mypy the hints required to make it happy? Or is this construct simply considered "bad" ?

Comment: A similar question (mine): [PyCharm gives me a type warning about my metaclass; mypy disagrees](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76224359).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this error message implies to me that `mypy` just doesn't want to accept an `A.__new__` that doesn't return a subtype of `A`. This is probably reasonable, although fo course, in Python, you *don't have* to do that.

I found this interesting discussion in a [mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1020) where none-other than Guido  van Rossum himself states that he doesn't think this should ever happen.

Let me suggest a couple of alternatives 1) ditch the factory class:

```
import typing

class Thing:
    pass

_thing: Thing | None  = None
def thing_factory() -> Thing:
    global _thing
    if _thing is None:
        _thing = Thing()
    return _thing


thing = thing_factory()
same_thing = thing_factory()

assert thing is same_thing
```

I actually think the above is more pythonic anyway, the intermediate `ThingFactory` class serves no purpose. But the mutable global state bothers you, you can do something like:

```
import typing

class Thing:
    pass

class ThingFactory:
    _thing: typing.ClassVar[Thing]
    @classmethod
    def get_thing(cls) -> Thing:
        if not hasattr(cls, "thing"):
            cls._thing = Thing()
        return cls._thing

get_thing = ThingFactory.get_thing

thing = get_thing()
same_thing = get_thing()

assert thing is same_thing
```

Again, the intermediate class bothers me. And you do need to use `ThingFactory.get_thing()` instead of `ThingFactory()`, but it looks lie in practice you just use a function, `get_thing` anyway. I think that may be an adequate trade-off if you just want to placate mypy.

Finally, I should point out, that your original code raises no errors with [`pyright`](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright):

```
jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~jarrivillaga$ pyright test.py
No configuration file found.
...
Assuming Python platform Darwin
Searching for source files
Found 1 source file
0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 infos

Completed in 0.545sec
```

Comment: ty, particularly for addressing whether it's pythonic for A.__new__ to return something other than A (or a subclass thereof). Given that GVR himself says no, I'll re-implement using one of your methods. Ty again!

Answer (score 1):

Type checking of mypy (or any other Python type checker, for that matter) does not happen at runtime.

And it insists, quite reasonably, that a return value of the `__new__()` method of a class should be an instance of the class itself.

So in the first error, mypy complains about the return type of `__new__()`. Separately, in the second error, it complains that the return type of `get_thing()` doesn't match the type hint.

You can create a singleton using the [singleton-decorator](https://pypi.org/project/singleton-decorator/) library. Or if you don't want non-standard library dependencies, you can check out its [source code](https://github.com/Kemaweyan/singleton_decorator/blob/master/singleton_decorator/decorator.py) - it's pretty short and concise.

Comment: Have you actually checked if using that library/code would solve the typing issues? I suspect since it is untyped, it would just lead to more of a headache. And note, it would replace your class that you decorated with *another class*, and that will wreak all sorts of havoc for the static analysis

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is the use the built-in `functools.cache`:

```
from functools import cache

class Thing:
    pass


@cache
def get_thing() -> Thing:
    return Thing()


get_thing() is get_thing() # True
```